# How to fade image out on scroll?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to fade an image out on scroll - and have looked up a few solutions online, however, am unable to find a way to get it to work with my code.  Usually, when I try, the image will disappear altogether, so I was hoping to get some help on this.

> I found a way online that looked quite simple, so I've been trying to
>   get this to work.

```css
.background {
        background-image:url(assets/images/gif/rainspeechpanel.gif);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        height: 150%;
        width: 100%;
        position:relative;
        background-size:cover;
        overflow-y: scroll;    
    }
    
    [data-aos="fade"] {
      opacity: 0;
      transition-property: opacity;
    }
    
    [data-aos="fade"].aos-animate {
    }
```

```html
    <div class="background"; style="centre"; data-aos="fade"; aos-duration="500">
    
        <a href="index.html"><div class="button"><img src="assets/images/buttons/home_rollover_1.png" onmouseover="this.src='assets/images/buttons/home_rollover_2.png'"onmouseout="this.src='assets/images/buttons/home_rollover_1.png'" width="35" height="40">
        </div>
        </a>
    
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with Javascript

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $(".top").css("opacity", 1 - $(window).scrollTop() / 250);
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 1000px;
}

.top {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #aaa;
  height: 300px;
  opacity: 1;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'helvetica';
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #fff;
}

.title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top">
  <div class="title">Fade Away</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help - I tried this, but it's just resized my background image - should I be changing the class names to ones that are in my file?  I have 2 images stacked upon each other, and would like the first image to fade out when I scroll down to see the second image?  Thanks!

Comment: I gave it as a general example - you should only need to implement the javascript part and add on a "top" class to whatever you want to fade. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Add this jQuery code to your code:

```
<script>
        function showImages(el) {
            var windowHeight = jQuery(window).height();
            $(el).each(function() {
                var thisPos = $(this).offset().top;

                var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
                if (topOfWindow + windowHeight - 200 > thisPos) {
                    $(this).addClass("fadeIn");
                }
            });
        }

        // if the image in the window of browser when the page is loaded, show that image
        $(document).ready(function() {
            showImages('.button');
        });

        // if the image in the window of browser when scrolling the page, show that image
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            showImages('.button');
        });
</script>
```